# Does the LOAD DATA INFILE disabled on most shared hostings?

Tags: mysql, database, load, hosting

I want to use LOAD DATA INFILE to significantly faster MySQL import process in my plugin software. I hear that some shared hostings disabled this (cool) feature. Is it correct? If yes, why they did it and is it a possibility to emulate this somehow? My software is intended to run successfully on shared hostings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `LOAD DATA INFILE` requires special privileges, these are not provided on most shared hosting providers:

> Non-`LOCAL` load operations read text files located on the server. For
>   security reasons, such operations require that you have the `FILE`
>   privilege. See Section 6.2.1, “Privileges Provided by MySQL”. Also,
>   non-`LOCAL` load operations are subject to the `secure_file_priv` system
>   variable setting. If the variable value is a nonempty directory name,
>   the file to be loaded must be located in that directory. If the
>   variable value is empty (which is insecure), the file need only be
>   readable by the server.
>
> Using `LOCAL` is a bit slower than letting the server access the files
>   directly, because the file contents must be sent over the connection
>   by the client to the server. On the other hand, you do not need the
>   `FILE` privilege to load local files.

*From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)*

MySQL documentation has a [section dedicated to optimizing `INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html), which has hints on speeding up insert operations.

Comment: Does it mean LOAD DATA LOCAL is enabled on most of the shared hostings?

Comment: No it is not enabled.